# Looking for specific values/relationships pertaining to infinite products

Tags: products, infinite-product

I am looking for any information related to these functions: $$f(s)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+\frac{1}{k^s})^k$$
$$g(s)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty k^{\frac{1}{k^s}}$$

Which converge for $\Re(s)>1$. I know that $\log(g(s))$ is a Dirichlet series with character $\chi(k)=\log(k)$. Besides that I don't really know where to look.

Comment: $\log f(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \log(1+k^{-s})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \sum_{m= 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+1} }{m}k^{-sm} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) n^{-s}$ where $a(n) = \sum_{m \ge 1, n^{1/m} \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{(-1)^{m+1} n^{1/m}}{m}$. What you wrote about $\chi(k) = \log k$ doesn't make any sense. Do you know what is a Dirichlet character ?

Comment: @reuns I seem to be confusing the Dirichlet Series with the [Dirichlet L Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function).